# IIS Manager does not have Management Service item in the server node

Tags: windows-10, iis

I have IIS running in Windows 10 Pro and am trying to enable remote management.

When the server node is selected on the left menu tree of IIS Manager, the right side under Manager shows only four items:

- Centralized Certificates
- Configuration Editor
- Feature Delegation
- Shared Configuration

There is no Management Service item as described in the documentation I see.

Under IIS in Turn Windows features on or off, I have installed:

- IIS Management Console
- IIS Management Scripts and Tools
- IIS Management Service

Is there anything else I must install?

Answer (score 2):

That Management Service icon only appears if you are managing a Windows Server.
It is not applicable to Windows 10.

The option also requires installing the
[Web Platform Installer (Web PI)](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx),
then you can add a lot of tools using this Web PI.
One of those tools is Management Service which can be enabled via Web PI.

References:

- [Configuring a Web Server for Web Deploy Publishing (Web Deploy Handler)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler)
- [Remote Administration for IIS Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/remote-administration-for-iis-manager)
  (for Windows Server 2008)